# Select just DAY from DATETIME in sql

Tags: php, sql, date

I have to select just the DAY from a DATETIME object in my sql database i found a lot of answers where they use GETDATE() but i always get errors that the function doesn't exist. Here is my query, the

```
-- `start` = DATETIME column

SELECT GETDATE() `start`, DAY(GETDATE()) 'Day Part' FROM events
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `start`, DAY(`start`) `Day Part` FROM events
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOW()` function, `GETDATE()` function belongs to `SQL SERVER` not `Mysql`

```
SELECT NOW() `start`, DAY(NOW()) `Day Part` 
FROM events
```

If you want to find the `Day` part from your `datetime` column then replace `NOW()` inside `DAY` function with your column name

```
SELECT `start`, DAY(`start`) `Day Part` 
FROM events
```

Comment: that returns today.. the DATETIME is a date somewhere in the future or past it's the start from an event like: 2017-01-01 00:00:00 where i want to select 01